# Excel web addin with Office365 E3 developer license

Tags: visual-studio, office365, excel-web-addins

I have been developing an Excel web component with Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 for a while with no particular problems until I installed an Office E3 developer license on my desktop without changing anything else.

Since then, no component works properly even the basic template supplied by Visual Studio (either 2019 or 2022): no icons in the command bar, nothing appears on the taskpane from html, break points on javascript not effective.

Only web components from Visual Studio Code work properly.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

An interim  workaround is proposed [here](https:////github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/issues/643)

Comment: The issue has been  recently fixed. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639421/excelwebaddin-with-office365-e3-developper-license